# How to add spacing between Legend and Chart in Recharts with absolute positioning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, legend, recharts

I'm using Recharts for the first time in my React project
I've positioned the legend of my BarChart component to the top right corner.
However, I'm struggling to add spacing between the legend and the chart itself. Since the legend is positioned absolutely, I can't set any margin directly on it.

When attempting to change the legend's style to relative positioning, the legend gets displayed under the chart, ignoring the align and verticalAlign properties

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
<BarChart data={data}
          barGap={8}>
    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" vertical={false}/>
    <XAxis tickFormatter={(index) => index + 1} tickMargin={16} tickLine={false}/>
    <YAxis orientation={"right"} tickMargin={16} axisLine={false} tickLine={false}/>
    <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip/>}/>
    <Legend
        align="right" verticalAlign="top"
        iconType="circle" iconSize={12}
        formatter={(value, entry) => {
            return <LegendText>{value} ({entry.payload.unit})</LegendText>
        }}/>
    <Bar name="Poids" unit="kg" dataKey="kilogram" fill="#282D30" barSize={7}
         radius={[10, 10, 0, 0]}/>
    <Bar name="Calories brûlées" unit="kCal" dataKey="calories" fill="#E60000" barSize={7}
         radius={[10, 10, 0, 0]}/>
</BarChart>
```

How can I add a specific amount of spacing (e.g., 65px) between the legend and the chart in this setup?

Thank you!